# Maven Build Error when I move my project to another system

Tags: maven

I am trying to setup Maven Project in another system which is perfectly working in my system.

But when I try to run in another system. It is throwing below error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'spring-security'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
```

Any idea how to resolve this error?

Note: I want to use Maven version 3.3.9 in the new system (I want to upgrade).

Comment: There are several download errors before those messages above and i  assume that you have something missed like migrating the settings.xml or not configured it yet etc. ?

Comment: What configuration are you mentioning in settings.xml?

Comment: I am thinking that I am getting error because of change in maven versions. But I dono how to resolve it.

Comment: Simply no..cause the error message shows downloads do not work...so i assume you have not migrated settings.xml or changed something but without a full log it is impossible to help here...

Comment: Ya. I think whatever you are saying is correct. I have seen that I need to put proxy details in settings.xml. But I don't have an idea about these proxy details? Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is Google to simple to use? https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html